# Count all the occurrences of the prefix string

Tags: python, string, optimization

Find the alphabet present at that location and determine the no of occurrences of the same alphabet preceding that location `n`.

**Input:**

> length = 9
>
> string = "abababbsa"
>
> n = 9

**Output:**

> 3

**Explanation:**

Find the alphabet at `nth` position 9 i.e `a`. Count all the occurrences before that index which is `3`.

**Code:**

```
length = int(input())
string = list(input())
n = int(input())
str1 = string[n-1]
print(string[0:n-1].count(str1))
```

The above code gives TLE. How can I optimize this?

Comment: is it "find all the occurrences" or "count all the occurrences"?

Comment: count all the occurences

Comment: well, your code seems very straight forward and correct, going over the minimum amount of chars as I understand. I hope someone comes up with an idea.

Comment: In this cace 9 is out of range, becouse indexing of list start from 0, what mean that you last index is 8

Answer (score 0):

Well It becomes easy if you use re ( regex )

```
import re
length = int(input())
my_string = input('Enter your string')
n = int(input())
print(len(re.findall(my_string[n-1],my_string[:n-1])))
```

So what is happening is we are finding all occurences of the character before n by slicing the string at n-1 and just getting the length of the list ( all occurences ).

Answer (score 0):

One way to optimize is to use string as usual in spite of converting it into a list:

`string = input()`

The complexity would now be O(n) where n is the input position, whereas, in your 
case, because the string was explicitly converted to list, the complexity was 
O(length of the string).